# Bash - logging what called my script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a script, 'setwakeup.sh'. I set the system up quite a while ago and it seems something is invoking the script when it shouldn't be, but I can't seem to find out what.

Is there something I can insert in setwakeup.sh which will log which process/user is running the script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`(date; ps $PPID) >> /your/call.log`

Comment: +1, but I would use a brace block instead of a subshell: `{ date; ps $PPID; } >> /your/call.log`